# MVC check box list - items incorrectly checked after post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

I've got an annoyance with what should be a really simply view that has a list of items that include checkboxes.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ApiKeys.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ApiKeys[i].Name, new { @class = "api-input-150" })</td>
                <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ApiKeys[i].Remove, new { @class = "api-input-50" })</td>
            </tr>    
        }
```

When the form submits I remove any items flagged to be removed and then return the view with the new set of data.

What I'm seeing is that if the list still contains an item with the same index as one of the rows that was removed on the post the item checkbox is checked incorrectly even though the value of the Remove property is set to false.

E.g. list of 3 items > remove item 2 > the 2nd item in the list is checked when the view renders.

list of 3 items > remove item 3 > no items are checked in the resultant view

list of 4 items > remove items 1 & 2 > the remaining items are both checked in the resultant view

If I refresh the page it then renders correctly so I've worked around this temporarily by doing a RedirectToAction to force an GET to the view instead of just returning the view from the POST but would like to know what's going wrong and how I can fix this properly.

Here's the actual code snippets from the two actions:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(GetSettings());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Model.Setup settings)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SaveSettings(settings);
        return View(GetSettings());
    }
    else
    {
        return View(settings);
    }
}
```

Given that my underlying data is all updated correctly and this only happens in the response from a POST I'm wondering if there's some kind of browser feature in play that is caching the checked state and overriding what my view is actually trying to render...

... or maybe there's a real simple error here that I'm missing from staring at it too long!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove any properties that you are modifying inside your POST action from the ModelState or the HTML helpers will still use the old values. For example:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    SaveSettings(settings);
    return View(GetSettings());
}
```

Comment: That's solved the problem thanks. Why do the helpers do this just for these check items?  Changes to other fields are all correctly displayed - it's only the checkboxes that exhibit this quirk.

Comment: @Chris W, this behavior is by design => all HTML helpers first look in ModelState when binding values and after that in the model. This behavior is not limited only to CheckBoxFor helper.

Comment: This issue has been bugging me for days.  Thank you.
The problem I was having was, I was updating a collection in a form, and if specifics criteria was met, then the item was removed from the collection.  However, the html generated from the view showed the old item that was removed.